# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 in recyclerview

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I need to retrieve a list of name from Firebase, after that the name list can display by using recyclerview. However, it displays java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 in my logcat which showed the error has happened in recyclerview class.Thanks in advance whoever has helped me :)

Below is the line which has the error :

```
holder.tname.setText(namelist1.get(position));
```

I don't know what's wrong to my code.
Here is my recyclerview class

```
public class MyRecyclerviewPAppointment extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerviewPAppointment.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<AppointmentObject> alist;
ArrayList<String> namelist1;

    public MyRecyclerviewPAppointment(Context c, ArrayList<AppointmentObject> t,ArrayList<String> namelist) {
        context = c;
        alist = t;
        namelist1=namelist;
    }
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyRecyclerviewPAppointment.MyViewHolder holder,final int position) {

     holder.tdate.setText(alist.get(position).getDate());
      holder.ttime.setText(alist.get(position).getTiming());
////////////error happened here////////////////////////
        holder.tname.setText(namelist1.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alist.size();
    }
}
```

Here is how I retrieve my data

```
 databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("appointment");
        databaseReference.orderByChild("userid").equalTo(userid1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    AppointmentObject thera= dataSnapshot1.getValue(AppointmentObject.class);
                    a.add(thera);
                    final String theraid = dataSnapshot1.child("theraid").getValue(String.class);


                    DatabaseReference refThera = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("alluser").child("thera");
                    refThera.child(theraid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot3) {

                            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot3.getChildren())
                            {
                                String text = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                namelist.add(text);
                            }
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            throw databaseError.toException();
                        }
                    });

                }

                adapter=new MyRecyclerviewPAppointment(MainActivityPAppointment.this, a,namelist);
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

here is my firebase structure
[image: table]

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have fewer items in `namelist` than there are in `alist`.

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return alist.size();
}
```

Since you tell the recycler view there are `alist.size()` items in the view, that's how many items it tries to draw. But then at some point, there is no corresponding item in `namelist`, so it throws an error.

The solution is likely to either make sure you have the same number of items in `alist` and `namelist`, or to only render the number of items you have in `namelist`.

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return namelist.size();
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question, actually i think both the ArrayList has the same number of element? in the first loop, it get the item that corresponds to user which curently logged in. in the second loop, it get the item according to one specific data that retrieve from the first loop

Comment: "i think both the ArrayList has the same number of element" The error message clearly indicates that this is not true. Since you didn't show how you populate `alist`, it's impossible to say why they're not the same length. If you're having a hard time fixing the issue, I'd recommend isolating it. This typically involves starting from scratch in a new app, and then adding minimal bits of code until you have the same problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).